# c# SetForegroundWindow and SendMessageTimeout

Tags: c#, windows

The problem: I want to make a screenshot of a window.

I use SetForegroundWindow to activate the window which belong to a different process.

To take a screenshot, I need to wait until the activated windows is finished drawing itself.

According to this article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=94745 I use this function call ...

```
IntPtr result = SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 5000, out IntPtr lResult);
```

... to wait for the window to become activated (completely painted on the screen).
But the function returns before the window is drawn. In most cases I caputure the screen before the window is painted (completely/at all).

So what is the best way to wait for Window, that got set to become ForegroundWindow, until the rendering of the window is completed?

---

Now I also tried...

- SendMessageTimeout with WM_PAINT
- UpdateWindow()
- RedrawWindow(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0x0400/*RDW_FRAME*/ | 0x0100/*RDW_UPDATENOW*/| 0x0001/*RDW_INVALIDATE*/);

without success.

Trying PrintWindow(...) resulted in an empty bitmap with Win7 style frame.

Only waiting long enough seem to do the trick. But simply waiting is exactly, what I did not want, because it take unnecessary much time.

Comment: _"to wait for the window to become activated (completely painted on the screen)."_ -- you are conflating "activated" with "painted". The two are not the same. All that the code you've referenced does is wait for the WM_ACTIVATE and subsequent synchronous messages to be processed. There's no guarantee that WM_PAINT will be among those, nor that even if it is, the process won't decide it has more things to paint later.

Comment: And is there a way to find out when the window is painted?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatewindow

Comment: WM_PAINT did not work. I updated the original post.